# Error: 'Raster map not found' in QGIS 2.18.1 GRASS tools

Tags: qgis, raster, tools

I get the same error in multiple QGIS GRASS tools and I don't understand the error. I have a raster surface height map with some no data spaces I want to fill.

The error occurs when using `r.fillnulls`, `r.resamp.bspline`, `r.in.lidar` and `r.surf.idw`.

The error I keep getting is:

> span style="color:darkgray">ERROR: Raster map
>   output2c10671429724b50a23f93a6b91af9fd not found.

[image]
The name of the output raster map is different when I change the input file or tool.

First I thought the problem occurred when trying to create a temp output file, so I put it on perm file in a different location but this didn't help.

Comment: please edit your question to add which version of QGIS and your operating system. Where did you try to put the permanent file?

Comment: I am using 2.18.1 on windows 7, i tried to save the file locally on the c:\\ disk.

Comment: Having a very similar problem, were you ever able to resolve this issue?